# What files are required for using dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to init DataTable but can't.

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "demo_page.css";
    @import "demo_table.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

1. What is wrong?
2. Is structure of table required?
3. Is data required?

> ```
> <table id="example">    
>     <thead>
>        <tr>
>            <th>Column 1</th>
>        </tr>
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
>         <tr>
>             <td>data</td>
>         </tr>
>     </tbody> 
> </table>
> ```

Comment: It seems to me that there is leak of header files. I remade their header to mine. The result is [it worked before] it [doesn't work after my changes].

Comment: Your one row of "data" is enough dummy data. You don't need to have a server-side data source or anything like that, unless you have passed parameters into the dataTable function asking for a resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only two files to initialize:

1. jQuery (however you want to include it); followed by
2. jquery.dataTables.js (or the minified version).

Your table will look crazy without appropriate CSS, (various spans are added to facilitate the sorting icons), but they're not necessary. They're just style.

If it's not initializing with those two files and a `$('#myTable').dataTable()` call (in the document ready function) then something else is going on and you will need to look at your JavaScript console to see what errors are being thrown.

Here it is in their jsbin environment: http://live.datatables.net/olofeg

No CSS, just the two JS files, a well-formed table, and calling `dataTable()` from the document ready function.

Answer (score 3):

To use datatable you have a lot of choices, one possibility is to have a well formed (with `<thead>` and `<tbody>`) HTML table to "transform"

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "demo_page.css";
    @import "demo_table.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="example">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Column 1</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
//initialize datatables
    (function($){
       $('#example').dataTable();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: probably it depends on folder structure.

Comment: @Anton of course this code requires that alle  the files are in the same folder (demo_table.css, demo_page.css, jquery.dataTables.js, jquery.js and the html file)

Comment: But not only these files. :) Which one I don't know probably we have to follow "their" folder structure.

Comment: @Anton of course you have to follow their structure..the structure must be reflecte in your `@import` and `src` attribute

Comment: I mean demo_page.css, demo_table.css, jquery.js and jquery.dataTables.js is not enough for DataTable initialization.

Comment: @Anton those four files are enough to run dataTables

Answer (score 1):

You must call dataTable function in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("example").dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I researched on a full day. Supposedly jQuery is used by a large
>   number of people, but I could not find a 'Single' blog which says what
>   all the "bare-minimum" stuff to be imported into your html/jsp for
>   making use of jQuery datatable functionalities... Hence I have
>   compiled this into a small html page as below (this is completely
>   working stuff, so please start off from here and build it your way.. )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>  
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#companies").dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
 
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="demo_jui">
                <table id="companies" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Company name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Town</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>Atlassian</th>
       <th>Paramatta</th>
       <th>Sydney</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Oracle</th>
       <th>Whitefield</th>
       <th>India</th>
      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
         </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```